# Meaning of "stays" in this example

Tags: meaning

From http://artofmanliness.com/2011/04/06/how-to-iron-shirt/

> Iron around buttons, never over them. Even if there is fabric laying
>   over the button, as in the case of a pocket with under-buttons or a
>   dress shirt with a hidden button down collar.  You can create a
>   permanent impression that will ruin the look of the shirt.  Be sure to
>   remove **shirt stays** as well.

I can't find a meaning for "stays" from those listed in [Google dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=definen+stay&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#hl=en&safe=off&client=ubuntu&hs=7fs&sa=X&channel=fs&q=stay&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&psj=1&ei=Ctg_UOLgMofo0QGZ1YHwCg&ved=0CB0QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=68c2fd627b28495a&biw=1361&bih=724). I wonder how to interpret it? Thanks!

Comment: It's noun #4 ("A device used as a brace or support") in the Google dictionary.

Answer (score 5):

They are (likely) talking about *[collar stays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collar_stays)*:

> Collar stays (sometimes known as collar sticks, bones, knuckles, tabs,
>   in the UK, collar stiffeners, and in Eastern Canada collar stiffs) are
>   shirt accessories.
>
> Collar stays are smooth, rigid strips of metal (such as brass,
>   stainless steel, or sterling silver), horn, baleen, mother of pearl,
>   or plastic, rounded at one end and pointed at the other, inserted into
>   specially made pockets on the underside of a man's shirt collar to
>   stabilize the collar's points. The stays ensure that the collar lies
>   flat against the collarbone, looking crisp and remaining in the
>   correct place. Often shirts come with plastic stays which may
>   eventually need to be replaced if they bend; metal replacements don't
>   have this problem.

[image]

However, there is another form of *[shirt stays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shirt_stays)*:

> elastic straps that connect the bottom of a dress shirt to the socks or feet.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Are stays only in the collar of a shirt?

Comment: @Tim No, women used to wear them in their bodices.

Comment: @Tim please see my updated answer.  As far as the generally stiff parts of a shirt go, as far as I know, the placket and cuffs would be stiff from starch, but not from stays.

Comment: @tchrist  Actually, "stays" (or a "pair of stays") were usually worn under the bodice. The 'boning' (flexible 'whalebone' stiffening pieces) was too costly to be incorporated in individual overgarments.